# jar files, pom files are not downloading in maven projects

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run my maven project, but in .m2 file I'm not seeing any jar files and pom files. In ecliplse I'm getting below error

**Error** -

```
"Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to repo1.maven.org (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1]"
```

I'm navigating "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" from my browser i'm able to access it.

In **.m2** folder I'm seeing below files
[image]

I'm using simple run configurations, please find it below
[image]

I'm not under any proxy
[image]

Comment: Did you try ticking "debug output"? Maven should tell you the exact URL it is trying to download the dependency from along with the error it is encountering.

Comment: Thanks Backslash, i getting below error -"  Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 " , " Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to repo1.maven.org (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connect timed out "

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Leviand: no Leviand, I'm not

Comment: Usually connection timed out means that the repository can't be reach, and that's a network problem. Check if the connection is without blocks (firewall?)

Comment: @Leviand: If it is network issue i couldn't download jar/pom files even from the browser r8?. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam no; I had the same issue of you: I was browsing the site, but I couldn't download dependencies. The problem for me was the proxy. Probably maven is using different ports than 80 / 443 .

Comment: @Leviand: if it is proxy, I can i fix it. can you please help me on it

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam take a look here -> https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html?